# Onelogin: Check if session is still valid - OpenID and SAML

Tags: session, authentication, openid, saml, onelogin

We have a custom IdP and several applications that use this IdP to authenticate using SAML and openID. The authentication happen when we check the credential with OneLogin.

Since we have a mix of SAML and opneID application, there is a way to know if the session is still valid in OneLogin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking whether the session is still valid depends on the protocol in use by the Relying Party that wants to perform this check: when using SAML one can use the `IsPassive=true` flag on the Authentication Request, when using OpenID Connect one can use `prompt=none` flag on such a request.

Answer (score 0):

What result are you trying to get here ? The once the SAML token or OIDC token has been validated and verified, the user is authenticated with the application and has a session with the application directly. Whether the user has a valid session with Onelogin doesn't impact the application behaviour until the application determines ( either through timeout or browser close or cookie cull.....whatever ) that the user is no longer authenticated and will push the user to Onelogin to authenticate again.

Are you trying to tie all application sessions to a valid Onelogin session ?

Hanz is correct in the use of the IsPassive flag, which will return a SAML response *only* if the IdP can do so without asking the user to authenticate again, which by default should mean they have a valid session. I've never tried that with Onelogin so your mileage may vary.